# Loop com Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou usando a seguinte lógica para um código:

```
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM CAT_GRUPO_APRESENTACAO cga WHERE GAPNM_CODIGO_PAI = 8427;
    DECLARE codigos := SELECT * FROM  CAT_GRUPO_APRESENTACAO cga WHERE GAPNM_CODIGO_PAI in(SELECT GAPNM_CODIGO FROM CAT_GRUPO_APRESENTACAO cga WHERE GAPNM_CODIGO_PAI = 8427);     
    SELECT * FROM CAT_GRUPO_APRESENTACAO cga WHERE GAPNM_CODIGO_PAI in(codigos)
END;
```

Em que eu pegaria todos os valores da coluna GAPNM_CODIGO, dadas no primeiro select, salvaria em uma variável, e usaria em um novo select usando o WHERE e o IN. Fazendo isso em forma de loop, ou seja, depois do primeiro SELECT do codigo pai, usaria os valores do GAPNM_CODIGO para a query do where in, e assim sucessivamente, até obter resultado nulo.

Estou com dificuldade em aplicar esta logica com o banco Oracle

Comment: já tentou usar o `FOR`? por exemplo `FOR item in (SELECT ....) LOOP  .. AQUI PODE USAR item.campo e fazer a sua lógica ...  END LOOP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BEGIN 
  FOR RPAI IN (SELECT * 
               FROM CAT_GRUPO_APRESENTACAO cga 
               WHERE GAPNM_CODIGO_PAI = 8427)
  LOOP
    FOR RFILHO IN (SELECT * 
                   FROM CAT_GRUPO_APRESENTACAO cga 
                   WHERE GAPNM_CODIGO_PAI = RPAI.GAPNM_CODIGO)
    LOOP
      /*FAZ ALGUMA COISA*/
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;               
END;
```

[Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1155)